# Add multiple output variables using purrr and a predefined function

Tags: r, function, purrr

Take this simple dataset and function (representative of more complex problems):

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
mult <- function(a,b,n) (a + b) * n
```

Using base R's `Map` I could do this to add 2 new columns in a vectorised fashion:

```
ns <- 1:2
x[paste0("new",seq_along(ns))] <- Map(mult, x["a"], x["b"], n=ns)
x
#  a b new1 new2
#1 1 2    3    6
#2 2 3    5   10
#3 3 4    7   14
```

`purrr` attempt via `pmap` gets close with a list output:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
x %>% select(a,b) %>% pmap(mult, n=1:2)
#[[1]]
#[1] 3 6
#
#[[2]]
#[1]  5 10
#
#[[3]]
#[1]  7 14
```

My attempts from here with `pmap_dfr` etc all seem to error out in trying to map this back to new columns.

How do I end up making 2 further variables which match my current `"new1"/"new2"`? I'm sure there is a simple incantation, but I'm clearly overlooking it or using the wrong `*map*` function.

There is some useful discussion here - [How to use map from purrr with dplyr::mutate to create multiple new columns based on column pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49816669/how-to-use-map-from-purrr-with-dplyrmutate-to-create-multiple-new-columns-base) - but it seems overly hacky and inflexible for what I imagined was a simple problem.

Comment: This is ugly but I don't think you are looking for this. `x %>% select(a,b) %>% pmap(mult, n=1:2) %>% bind_cols() %>% t()`

Comment: What about this one: `x[paste0("new",seq_along(ns))] <- pmap(list(x['a'], x['b'], ns), mult)`?

Comment: @mt1022 - that's a really good point that `pmap`/`Map` are directly analogous. The only problem being that I am trying to fit this into someone else's piped code. Is there a way to feed `x` into that `pmap` like the (non-working) `x %>% pmap(list(a,b,ns), mult)` - I'm still lost at this stage.

Comment: I cannot think of a better way to feed `a` and `b` from `x` to `pmap`. The most closest one I an get is `x %>% {list(.['a'], .['b'], ns)} %>% pmap(mult) %>% setNames(paste0('new', seq_along(ns))) %>% cbind(x)`.

Comment: @mt1022 - that's not too bad. Might be worth adding as a formal answer for completion's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach I've found (which is still not terribly elegant) is to pipe into `bind_cols`. To get `pmap_dfr` to work correctly, the function should return a named list (which may or may not be a data frame):

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
mult <- function(a,b,n) as.list(set_names((a + b) * n, paste0('new', n)))

x %>% bind_cols(pmap_dfr(., mult, n = 1:2))
#>   a b new1 new2
#> 1 1 2    3    6
#> 2 2 3    5   10
#> 3 3 4    7   14
```

To avoid changing the definition of `mult`, you can wrap it in an anonymous function:

```r
mult <- function(a,b,n) (a + b) * n

x %>% bind_cols(pmap_dfr(
    ., 
    ~as.list(set_names(
        mult(...), 
        paste0('new', 1:2)
    )), 
    n = 1:2
))
#>   a b new1 new2
#> 1 1 2    3    6
#> 2 2 3    5   10
#> 3 3 4    7   14
```

In this particular case, it's not actually necessary to iterate over rows, though, because you can vectorize the inputs from `x` and instead iterate over `n`. The advantage is that usually *n > p*, so the number of iterations will be [potentially much] lower. To be clear, whether such an approach is possible depends on for which parameters the function can accept vector arguments.

`mult` still needs to be called on the variables of `x`. The simplest way to do this is to pass them explicitly:

```r
x %>% bind_cols(map_dfc(1:2, ~mult(x$a, x$b, .x)))
#>   a b V1 V2
#> 1 1 2  3  6
#> 2 2 3  5 10
#> 3 3 4  7 14
```

...but this loses the benefit of `pmap` that named variables will automatically get passed to the correct parameter. You can get that back by using `purrr::lift`, which is an adverb that changes the domain of a function so it accepts a list by wrapping it in `do.call`. The returned function can be called on `x` and the value of `n` for that iteration:

```r
x %>% bind_cols(map_dfc(1:2, ~lift(mult)(x, n = .x)))
```

This is equivalent to

```r
x %>% bind_cols(map_dfc(1:2, ~invoke(mult, x, n = .x)))
```

but the advantage of the former is that it returns a function which can be `partial`ly applied on `x` so it only has an `n` parameter left, and thus requires no explicit references to `x` and so pipes better:

```r
x %>% bind_cols(map_dfc(1:2, partial(lift(mult), .)))
```

All return the same thing. Names can be fixed after the fact with `%>% set_names(~sub('^V(\\d+)$', 'new\\1', .x))`, if you like.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know I wasn't overlooking something really basic. I tried fudging around with `set_names` but wasn't having much luck. It's a bit unfortunate that the `mult` function needs editing beforehand.

Comment: You could wrap `mult` in an anonymous function instead: `x %>% bind_cols(pmap_dfr(., ~as.list(set_names(mult(...), paste0('new', 1:2))), n = 1:2))`, but at some point it's just really opaque code.

Comment: [purrrlyr](https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr)'s `by_row` and `invoke_rows` used to offer alternative ways to do these sorts of tasks: `x %>% purrrlyr::invoke_rows(mult, ., n = 1:2, .collate = 'cols')`, but are now sort-of deprecated. They're really interesting functions, though.

Comment: I've been thinking about this more, and provided the actual function is similar enough, it would be more efficient to vectorize over rows and iterate over `n`, which will usually result in a [potentially much] smaller number of iterations, here 2 instead of 3: `x %>% bind_cols(map_dfc(1:2, partial(lift(mult), .)))` It does depend on a function that can be vectorized across the row parameters, though.

Comment: Would you like to add that last comment to the answer? I think it is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possibility.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
n <- 1:2
x %>%
    mutate(val = pmap(., mult, n = n)) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    mutate(var = rep(paste0("new", n), nrow(.) / length(n))) %>%
    spread(var, val)
#  a b new1 new2
#1 1 2    3    6
#2 2 3    5   10
#3 3 4    7   14
```

Not pretty, so I'm also curious to see alternatives. A lot of excess comes about from `unnest`ing the `list` column and `spread`ing into new columns.

Here is another possibility using `pmap_dfc` plus an ugly `as.data.frame(t(...))` call

```
bind_cols(x, as.data.frame(t(pmap_dfc(x, mult, n = n))))
#  a b V1 V2
#1 1 2  3  6
#2 2 3  5 10
#3 3 4  7 14
```

---

### Sample data

```
x <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
mult <- function(a,b,n) (a + b) * n
```

Comment: Interesting. At least this answer can take the `mult` function as-is. I'll hold off and see if anyone else has a super-simple solution.

Comment: @thelatemail I also feel there must be an easier & more elegant way. I've played around with a double `map` call (see update); still not elegant (ugly `as.data.frame(t(...))` and the names still need to be fixed).

Comment: @thelatemail [update] Ok the double `map` call was not necessary, still have the ugly `as.data.frame(t(...))`...

Answer (score 1):

To mimic the input format for `Map`, we could call `pmap` from `purrr` in this way:

```
x[paste0("new",seq_along(ns))] <- pmap(list(x['a'], x['b'], ns), mult)
```

To fit this in a pipe:

```
x %>%
    {list(.['a'], .['b'], ns)} %>%
    pmap(mult) %>%
    setNames(paste0('new', seq_along(ns))) %>%
    cbind(x)

#   new1 new2 a b
# 1    3    6 1 2
# 2    5   10 2 3
# 3    7   14 3 4
```

Apparently, this looks ugly compared to the concise base R code. But I could not think of a better way.