# R: apply a function row-wise to a table, passing values from a look-up table as arguments

Tags: r, iteration, purrr

Here’s a row-wise iteration problem that I’ve been trying to solve with purrr::pmap, but no luck.

I start with a table of raw scores:

`rawscore_table <- data.frame(rawscore = 10:14, SS1 = NA, SS2 = NA)`

```
  rawscore SS1 SS2
1       10  NA  NA
2       11  NA  NA
3       12  NA  NA
4       13  NA  NA
5       14  NA  NA
```

There are two empty columns, SS1 and SS2, whose values I want to obtain by applying a function to each row:

`SS1 = rawscore + x + y`

`SS2 = rawscore + x + y`

The values of `x` and `y` are found in a lookup table:

`lookup_table <- data.frame(SS = c('SS1', 'SS2'), x = 1:2, y = 3:4)`

```
   SS x y
1 SS1 1 3
2 SS2 2 4
```

The solution I’m looking for will calculate the values of column `rawscore_table$SS1` by finding the values of `x` and `y` in the `SS1` row of `lookup_table`, and it will calculate the values of column `rawscore_table$SS2` by finding the values of `x` and `y` in the `SS2` row of `lookup_table`.

So the code has to refer to the name of the **column** in `rawscore_table` in order to pluck values from the corresponding **row** of `lookup_table`.

The desired output looks like this:

```
  rawscore   SS1   SS2
1       10    14    16
2       11    15    17
3       12    16    18
4       13    17    19
5       14    18    20
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I struggled with similar logic in purrr - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978138/add-multiple-output-variables-using-purrr-and-a-predefined-function - and never really got something that seemed as clean as `Map` (base) or `pmap` (purrr) and matching left and right-hand-sides of a `<-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to join `rawscore` and `lookup`:

```
rawscore_table %>%
  gather(SS, val, -rawscore) %>%
  left_join(lookup_table, by = 'SS') %>%
  mutate(val = rawscore + x + y, x = NULL, y = NULL) %>%
  spread(SS, val)

#  rawscore SS1 SS2
#1       10  14  16
#2       11  15  17
#3       12  16  18
#4       13  17  19
#5       14  18  20
```

Comment: Thanks to all for your input. The best solution for me is utubun's because it is based in tidyverse and uses functions I understand well. akrun's tidyverse solution is elegant, but I need to understand quotation better to feel confident using it.

Comment: Thanks @DSH. I think anyone can learn something new reading akrun's answers.

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to get the `rowSums` of the numeric columns of 'lookup_table', add (`+`) with the first column of 'rawscore_table', assign the output back to the columns except the first column

```
rawscore_table[-1] <- lapply(as.list(rowSums(lookup_table[-1])), `+`, 
           rawscore_table[,1])
```

---

Or replicate the `rowSums` output and add with the first column

```
rawscore_table[as.character(lookup_table$SS)] <- rawscore_table$rawscore + 
            rep(rowSums(lookup_table[-1]), each = nrow(rawscore_table))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
lookup_table %>% 
    transmute(SS, xy = x + y) %>%
    deframe %>%
    as.list %>%
    imap_dfc(~ 
             rawscore_table  %>%
                 transmute(!! .y :=  .x + rawscore)) %>% 
    bind_cols(rawscore_table[1], .)
#   rawscore SS1 SS2
#1       10  14  16
#2       11  15  17
#3       12  16  18
#4       13  17  19
#5       14  18  20
```