# mutate several columns based on single condition

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10)
```

Can I mutate several columns based on a single condition?

For example, I can do this:

```
df %>% mutate(y = if_else(x>3,"Y","N"), z = if_else(x>3,"YY","NN"))
```

but since the condition is the same (`x>3`) I was wondering if there may be another way without having to repeat it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

Thanks for the comment from @thelatemail, and here is an approach of your interest

```
df[c("y","z")] <- lapply(list(c("Y","N"), c("YY","NN")), \(x) ifelse(df$x > 3, x[1], x[2])  )
```

---

## Previous

Probably you can try

```
cbind(
    df,
    `row.names<-`(data.frame(
        y = c("N", "Y"),
        z = c("NN", "YY")
    )[(df$x > 3) + 1, ], NULL)
)
```

or a `dplyr` version

```
df %>%
    cbind({
        data.frame(
            y = c("N", "Y"),
            z = c("NN", "YY")
        )[((.)$x > 3) + 1, ]
    }) %>%
    `row.names<-`(NULL)
```

which gives

```
    x y  z
1   1 N NN
2   2 N NN
3   3 N NN
4   4 Y YY
5   5 Y YY
6   6 Y YY
7   7 Y YY
8   8 Y YY
9   9 Y YY
10 10 Y YY
```

---

Or, what about using `ifelse` like this (but this is inefficient, I would NOT recommend it)?

```
cbind(
    df,
    with(
        df,
        do.call(
            rbind,
            ifelse(x > 3,
                list(data.frame(y = "Y", z = "YY")),
                list(data.frame(y = "N", z = "NN"))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

which gives

```
    x y  z
1   1 N NN
2   2 N NN
3   3 N NN
4   4 Y YY
5   5 Y YY
6   6 Y YY
7   7 Y YY
8   8 Y YY
9   9 Y YY
10 10 Y YY
```

Comment: It doesn't really answer OP's question as posed, but I think it becomes a lot nicer using base assignment in this instance - `df[c("y","z")] <- lapply(list(c("Y","N"), c("YY","NN")), \(x) ifelse(df$x > 3, x[1], x[2])  )`

Comment: @thelatemail yes, that makes sense, and your solution is added in the the answer, thanks for your feedback

Comment: Thanks Thomas - no need to add the comment as the primary answer though. I think your previous suggestions all fit much better for a dplyr/piped logic, which was what the original question was about.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another solution using `dplyr`, `purrr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df |>
  mutate(new = map(x, ~if_else(.x > 3,
                               tribble(
                                 ~y, ~z,
                                 "Y", "YY"), 
                               tribble(
                                 ~y, ~z,
                                 "N", "NN")))) |>
  unnest(new)

# A tibble: 10 × 3
#       x y     z    
#   <int> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 N     NN   
# 2     2 N     NN   
# 3     3 N     NN   
# 4     4 Y     YY   
# 5     5 Y     YY   
# 6     6 Y     YY   
# 7     7 Y     YY   
# 8     8 Y     YY   
# 9     9 Y     YY   
#10    10 Y     YY
```

Comment: That's interesting - I think this might actually be adapted as a way to solve a question of mine from ages ago more cleanly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51978138/add-multiple-output-variables-using-purrr-and-a-predefined-function - thanks.

Comment: This is a good answer but you don't need to iterate over `x`.  Try `df |> mutate(across(x, ~ if_else(.x > 3, tibble(y = "Y", z = "YY"), tibble(y = "N", z = "NN")), .unpack = "{inner}"))`.