# Column-wise operations based on column-name prefixses

Tags: r, dplyr

Please consider:

```
require(dplyr)

my_data <- 
  data.frame(a.x = sample(1100),
             b.x = sample(1100),
             a.y = sample(1100),
             b.x = sample(1100))

my_data %>%
  mutate(a = a.x + a.y,
         b = b.x + b.y)
```

Is it possible to pass functions on sets of columns based on their common prefix with `dplyr::mutate_at` `.vars` and `.funs`?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49816669/1270695)?

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr library allows one to apply a function (or a set of functions) to a set of columns.  The below example adds a sum column of columns that begin with "a" and adds a standard deviation column for columns that begin with "b":

```
my_data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    sum = sum(c_across(starts_with("a"))),
    sd = sd(c_across(starts_with("b")))
    )
```